# Eclipse Plugin Development stop button in progress bar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runtime

My plugin runs a job and is shown in progress bar but i am unable to stop the job from progress bar , i figured out there is IProgressMonitor.setcanceled(True) but i can't figure out where or how can there be a listener to the stop button on progress bar

For your reference https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html#isCanceled()

Comment: It's not via a listener. Your job has to do `if (monitor.isCanceled()) return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;`: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_jobs_progress.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not via a listener. Your job has to execute the following on a regular basis (say a few times per second):

```
if (monitor.isCanceled())
    return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
```

Otherwise, hitting the stop button will not stop the running job.

See: [Eclipse help: Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Reporting progress](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_jobs_progress.htm)